# Change data format in existing field in mysql

Tags: mysql

In my db I have column in which there is about 1k~ records. All records have name field in which is overwrite also data. For eg. "name 7/24/2006". I need to change format mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy. Correctly it should be 24/07/2006. I tried to add this function: https://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/ and run

```
SELECT regex_replace('(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)$','$2/$1/$3',column_name`) `column_name` 
FROM` `table_name`
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: If your "dates" are in the format `mm/dd/yyyy` then they are probably stored as `varchar`, which is a generally bad idea.  Instead, get those dates into a `date`, `datetime`, or `timestamp`, using a nice accepted format like `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: If you are trying to modify the data you will need to use an `UPDATE` statement rather than `SELECT` but this is less important than the advice in the previous comment - there's no good reason to store dates as strings in MySQL.

Comment: Fix your database, not the garbage you have stored in it

Comment: use a date field as suggested. please, for the love of humanity.

Answer (score 1):

You should be storing date values *as true date-typed fields* in MySQL.  When you do this, you can view the date in whatever "output format" you like.  (Or, several different ones.)  This simply *presents* the date in a different way: it has no effect on the stored value itself.